# Segmentation fault when writing char array to file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

When I run the following code, I get a *"Segmentation fault"* at `fprintf(outfile, "%s", inputline[j]);`.

I am unable to understand what is the cause for the error. I am relatively new to C, can someone please help me resolve the error?

```
void test(char *inputline) {
    FILE *outfile = fopen("results.txt", "w");   
    if (!outfile) {
        perror("Error while opening file: ");
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) { // I only want to be write the first 20 characters to the file that is why I have the iteration till only 20 and added [j], is that correct way to do it?
            fprintf(outfile, "%s", inputline[j]);
        }
    }
}

//Function call
    ...
    char inputline[40] = "hello world 123 456"; //passed to the function above
    test(inputline);
```

Comment: You are passing a character (inputline[j]) to fprintf but the format specifier is expecting a string (char *).

Comment: You have provided a `char` for `fprintf` needing a `char*` pointer. The low value of a `char` where an address is needed, is likely to segfault when dereferenced. You need `"%c"`

Comment: second to last line is missing a semicolon, the function is never closed.

Comment: Hint: changing the sample code provide completely without remark is not a big help

Comment: I just updated my code, sorry for missing out details.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just updated my code, sorry for missing out details.

Comment: @Anna ok but please post *real* code, the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format specifier `%s` in

```
fprintf(outfile, "%s", inputline[j]);
```

expects a `char *` variable, but you are actually passing a `char` (j <sup>th</sup> element of `inputline` array).

The reason why a segmentation fault occurs is that `fprintf` tries to "access" the memory location poited by the passed character. And since it will be very likely an **invalid address** the OS will complain about the attempt to access the memory outside the *space* assigned to your application.

You can either print to file *char by char*, keeping the for-loop and using `%c` format

```
 for(int j=0; j<20; ++j)
 {
     fprintf(outfile, "%c", inputline[j]);
 }
```

or print the whole string keeping  the `%s`  format, passing the whole array and getting rid of the for-loop:

```
fprintf(outfile, "%s", inputline);
```

Note: in the first case 20 characters will be written, anyway. In the second case "length+1" characters  because of the string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: For instance, if I want to use the ```fprintf(outfile, "%c", inputline[j]);``` and I only loop 5 times and then I want to append a '-' to the last character after 5, how can I add it to this logic?

Comment: @Anna Add `if (i == 5) fprintf(outfile, "%c", '-');` inside the loop

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Btw won't `i` make a better loop variable here? `j` is usually used in nested loops. Moreover, OP doesn't even have a declaration of `j`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni And you are expected to correct it when you write a solution.

Comment: @Anna do you want do it preserving the original string or you can modify it? Do you want substitute every space or only the first one?

Comment: @ArdentCode, honestly using `j` rather than `i` is not a mistake. Otherwise I would have corrected it.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni That's just the first part of my comment, it's good to familiarize beginners to such conventions. The mistake is mentioned in the second part: *"missing declaration of variable `j`"* (You should have edited your answer instead of editing the question)

Comment: @ArdentCoder I admit I never heard of such convention in 15ys.. especially because we don't have inner loops (and the copied code is probably part of a bigger program in which `i` was used elsewhere). Talking about the initialization.. well in SO answers often little snippets of code can be used in order hilight mistake and corrections. They don't have to compile. :) Anyway I'll add the initializer... ;)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni See WeatherVane's comments under the question, they should provide minimal reproducible example. And if there are errors like missing semicolon, missing initializer, you shouldn't edit them out of their question. Correct it in the answer and let them know of all the errors.

Comment: Updated it to use i

Comment: @Anna: please do not keep modifying the question for fix mistakes, it makes comments and answers inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code that causes the segmentation fault is you pass a `char` value `inputline[j]` to `printf` for a `%s` argument, which expects a string pointer. This has undefined behavior.

To write at most the first 20 characters of the string, you can use `%.20s` as the format specifier. Also do not forget to close the file:

```c
void test(const char *inputline) {
    FILE *outfile = fopen("results.txt", "w");   
    if (outfile == NULL) {
        perror("Error while opening file: ");
    } else {
        // print at most 20 bytes from inputline
        fprintf(outfile, "%.20s\n", inputline);
        fclose(outfile);
    }
}
```

Note that if needed, this *maximum* count can be a variable with the `%.*s` format:

```
        int limit = 20;
        fprintf(outfile, "%.*s\n", limit, inputline);
```